# What is the correct way to correctly visualize a component React in top of another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to properly render my different components with the HTML/CSS sidebar with React Routes and Apollo.

I have a sidebar that correctly renders to the left of the screen and a little navbar on top of it, the space for the component is not being blocked by any css property.

The expected output is:

[image: Expected Output]

The actual output:

[image: Actual Output]

I've tried to place all the Routes inside the sidebar but every time I click on them, they don't load at all, the URL changes but the content doesn't and I need to reload the webpage for it take some effect. The help would be very much appreciated.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import {ApolloProvider} from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import 'bootswatch/dist/flatly/bootstrap.min.css';

import Nav from './components/Nav'
import Home from './components/pages/Home'
import About from './components/pages/About'
import Articles from './components/article/Articles'
import Article from './components/article/Article'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'url in here'
});


const App = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav/>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/Articles' component={Articles} />
        <Route exact path='/Articles/:id' component={Article} />
        <Route exact path='/About' component={About} />


      </div>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
export default App;
```

Nav.js component

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as  Link} from 'react-router-dom'; 

export default function Nav() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                </Link>
                .
                .
                .
            </nav>

            <div id="content">
                <nav className="navBar" > 

                </nav>

                <div className ="ComponentRender">
                    Here's where the component should be rendered
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Apollo but I think you should move your routes from the App component to the Nav component, so the code would be:

**App component:**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav/>
      </div>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

**And the Nav component:**

```
export default function Nav() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                </Link>
                .
                .
                .
            </nav>

            <div id="content">
                <nav className="navBar" > 

                </nav>

                <div className ="ComponentRender">
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/Articles' component={Articles} />
                    <Route exact path='/Articles/:id' component={Article} />
                    <Route exact path='/About' component={About} />
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Don't forget to move imports from App to Nav as well.